# JS: No contents in array from parent class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using two classes in javascript.

class Challenge and class Modules, that extends Challenge.

in Challenge i have this constructor:

```
constructor() {
    this.handles = [];
}
```

and this method:

```
bla() {

    let elmnts = document.querySelectorAll("p"); // 5x
    
        for(let i=0; i < elmnts.length; i++) {
        
            let elmnt = elmnts[i];
            this.handles[elmnt['id']] = elmnt; // saves the handles to each element in separate array for later use
        
        }

}
```

in the child Class i am trying to use this "this.handles" array, but it is always empty.

It is not "undefined" but it is an empty array as i defined it in the constructor. its like the entries have never been set... but they are (as console.log() shows, when i insert it directly after the for()-loop)

```
console.log(this.handles); // --> []
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: we might need to see more code

Comment: i tried to, but its too much and it seems to me like a more general question.

Comment: whats value of `elmnt['id']`?

Comment: Javascript has **only index-based arrays**, not associative arrays like PHP. If you need the latter, use an object. To add something to an array, use `push()`. Or try `this.handles[i] = elemnt;`.

Comment: ok, that might be a good point :)
what would be the best alternative in order to get an entry that is similar as calling array['key_string']?

Answer (score 2):

`this.handles` is an array. So when you are doing `this.handles[elmnt['id']]`, `elmnt['id']` returns a string, whereas an array expects (positive) integer for index. So the elements are not set in the array.

Maybe you meant `this.handles` to be an object?

```js
class Ex1 {
  constructor() {
    this.handles = {};
  }

  bla() {

    let elmnts = document.querySelectorAll("p"); // 5x

    for (let i = 0; i < elmnts.length; i++) {

      let elmnt = elmnts[i];
      this.handles[elmnt['id']] = elmnt; // saves the handles to each element in separate array for later use
    }
    
  }
}

class Ex2 extends Ex1 {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
  
  m1(){
    console.log(this.handles);
  }
}

let p1 = new Ex2();
p1.m1();
p1.bla();
p1.m1();
```

```html
<p id="one">1</p>
<p id="two">2</p>
<p id="three">3</p>
<p id="four">4</p>
<p id="five">5</p>
```

Comment: *is an array, not an object* No. It's both, that is why OP sees the properties they are setting in `bla()`.

Comment: @connexo I tried putting a `console.log` after the for loop but I also got an empty array.

Comment: Ofc it is, see my answer.

Comment: @connexo I got it. I didn't mean the literal meaning of object. I just meant it is not like a user defined `{}`

Comment: It **is** a `{}` internally, just one that implements the *iterable interface* and inherits from `Array.prototype`, and that implements a special property access syntax that allows for using `[index]` access.

Comment: @user7213923 Can you please accept the answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the following things:

In Javascript...

- ... Arrays are always index-based (0 pointing to the first array element).
- ... you append elements to an array using `arr.push(el)`.
- ... Arrays are **also** objects, so adding arbitrary properties also works (which is what you are doing by using the `p` element id as a key and assigning it the element reference). See this example:

[image]

If you need an array (which preserves order and can easily be iterated later on), just spread the `NodeList` you got from `querySelectorAll('p')` into the array using the ES6 spread syntax `...`:

```
this.handles = [...document.querySelectorAll("p")];
```